# Angular Get value from string Enum using integer

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, type-conversion, roles

```
export enum RoleTypesEnum {
    RoleA = 'Role is A',
    RoleB = 'Role is B',
}

// in TS file
public RoleTypesEnum = RoleTypesEnum;
```

I want to get string value (ex ***Role is B***) from enum using an integer.

If I type in HTML or TS file
`console.log(RoleTypesEnum[0])`
it prints *undefined*.

Because I receive integer from backend (ex: JSON -> RoleTypes: 0 or 1).

I can make a pipe and get enum values using `Object.values(RoleTypesEnum);`, but I am wondering for the best practice. The pipe solution: [Angular Pipe extracts from Enum values, but generic for any Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71797527/9442199)

**Backend-Frontend synchronicity**

The database stores the enum as integers. In backend (ASP.NET), DTO and models have field with enum type. When Controller returns, it automatically returns an integer in JSON from the enum.

1. If from backend I return ***string*** value (json: "roleB") instead of integer (json: 1). I need a conversion from Enum to string before returning the JSON. And I feel like wrecking with the DB and backend design.
2. If from backend I return ***integer*** (**current question case**), I can't have custom string values. Because the only data I have is an integer and 'RoleTypesEnum[1]' => undefined.
   Unless I set the enum with integers

```
export enum RoleTypesEnum {
    RoleA = 0,
    RoleB = 1,
}
```

But then I can't have custom string values (ex: "Role is B").

Comment: I find your way of doing quite clean and the question is interesting. IMHO, the real problem is a design problem. The backend is not supposed to know in which order the enum values are defined by the frontend. It would be better to exchange the values as strings instead.

Comment: The best practice would be to import this Enum class into your component, and then console.log(this.RoleTypesEnum.RoleA). It appears you're trying to log this as an array, this is just a straight up object with key value pairs

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Updated the question regarding your observation 'Backend-Frontend synchronicity'.

Comment: @GarrettWitzenburg I get from backend only integer. this.RoleTypesEnum.RoleA works but I don't know which to show on UI RoleA or RoleB. I know only dinamically from integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to have custom strings in this way:

**Shared/enums-descriptions.ts**

```typescript
export const MyTypesEnumDescription: {
    [key in MyTypesEnum]: string;
} = {
    [MyTypesEnum.Standard]: 'Standard',
    [MyTypesEnum.Advanced]: 'Advanced Stage',
    [MyTypesEnum.Intermediate]: 'Intermediate Stage',
};
```

**MyClass.ts**

```
public selectBoxItemList = [
    new SelectListItem({
        value: MyTypesEnum.Advanced,
        text: MyTypesEnumDescription.InvalidCall,
    }),
```