# Angular Pipe extracts from Enum values, but generic for any Enum

Tags: angular, string, enums, type-conversion, pipe

I have an enum with strings assigned to elements. Unfortunately, it does not work with integers as indexes. RoleTypesEnum[0] => undefined. I made a Pipe which solves this problem.

```
export enum RoleTypesEnum {
    RoleA = 'Role is A',
    RoleB = 'Role is B',
}

//HTML ('opt' integer received from backend)
{{ RoleTypesEnum[opt] | enumIntToDescription}}
```

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'enumIntToDescription',
})
export class EnumIntToDescriptionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): string {
        return Object.values(RoleTypesEnum )[value];
    }
}
```

But I want to make it generic to work for any Enum type, not only *RoleTypesEnum*.
Can there be a solution to work for any enum? Maybe with generics EnumIntToDescriptionPipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make it generic, you can pass the value of enum to the pipe.

```
{{ opt | enumIntToDescription: RoleTypesEnum }}
```

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'enumIntToDescription',
})
export class EnumIntToDescriptionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    // enum object on which you want this pipe to work
    transform(value: number, enum: any): any {
        return Object.values(enum)[value];
    }
}
```

In your component, you can pass the enum value to the pipe and it will work as expected.

Comment: A clean solution. I do believe though that it is better to use a variable inside the HTML pipe, instead of the enum itself, e.g. `{{ opt | enumIntToDescription: roleTypesEnum }}` and declare a variable inside the .ts file casting it to the actual enum; `roleTypesEnum: RoleTypesEnum`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solutions above but what worked for me was doing something more specific to the case:

My EnumToDescriptionPipe file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

export enum EnumTipoDeUsuario{
    ROLE_SUPPLIER = 'Third party Supplier',
    ROLE_USER = 'User'
} 

@Pipe({
    name: 'enumToDescription',
})
export class EnumToDescriptionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: EnumTipoDeUsuario,): any{
        return EnumTipoDeUsuario[value];
    }
}
```

My HTML:

```
{{element.profile | enumToDescription}}
```

As I said this is a more specific, not generic, solution which I preferred.

**Important**! For those using **Angular**:
If you still cant apply the pipe or is receiving an **error** remember to declare it in **app.module** and in **component_name.module**

I particularly created an **ApplicationPipesModule** for my pipes declaration and declared it in **app.module** and in the **component_name.module**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CaptalizePipe, 
    EnumIntToDescriptionPipe
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [
    CaptalizePipe,
    EnumIntToDescriptionPipe,
  ],
})
export class ApplicationPipesModuleModule {}
```